# How to set a differnet opacity for a TextView's background and its text (only using XML)?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I want to make a translucent EditText view with a visible hint text.

my end goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Lgl.jpg

I tried to set the alpha of the EditText view to "0.1" but it affects the visibility of the text as well. I then tried a different shade for the text and background but I still do not get the desired effect. I then tried wrapping it in a layout and setting the alpha of the layout but once again the text's opacity is also affected.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="286dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:alpha=".1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

my own work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCH5y.jpg

Comment: For future reference, you might want to post your images directly to your question. I'm guessing that's what the down vote is for : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277846/779956

Comment: @Erik Apparently, I did not have enough "reputation" in order to do so. Would it otherwise have been better if I stated this in my post?

Comment: sorry I didn't know that was a restriction. I don't know if stating that in a question is a good idea. I'm not really sure why you got a downvote. Did z85510 answer your question?

Comment: @Erik well not directly. i noticed he created the translucent effect from just the hex code so i went to search it up and found out you could adjust the opacity by adding 2 more digits at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="286dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="#33FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```